# How to start the list in a certain line through Pandas into a single line, as shown in the figure

Tags: pandas

How to start the list in a certain line through Pandas into a single line, as shown in the figure.
[image]

Comment: `df.explode('SubjectId')`?

Comment: i dont understand, can you explain a bit more pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that your dataframe is named `df`, use [**`pandas.DataFrame.explode`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) as shown below :

```
df['SubjectId'] = df['SubjectId'].str.strip('[]').str.split(',')

out = df.explode('SubjectId')
```

**Note** : Remove the first line if the values of the column `SubjectId` are `'list'`.

```
print(out)

   QuestionId  User Id  Answerl Id  IsCorrect  CorrectAnswer  AnswerValue SubjectId
0         898     2111      280203          1              2            2         3
0         898     2111      280203          1              2            2        49
0         898     2111      280203          1              2            2        62
0         898     2111      280203          1              2            2        70
1         898     4884     1355100          0              2            4         3
1         898     4884     1355100          0              2            4        49
1         898     4884     1355100          0              2            4        62
1         898     4884     1355100          0              2            4        70
2         898     3131      481614          0              2            4         3
2         898     3131      481614          0              2            4        49
2         898     3131      481614          0              2            4        62
```